# Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason Runtime.ExitError ==> Using a Docker Image for building a Lambda function

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a Lambda function that executes every time it receives a POST request. In this case, I am building a Docker Image (the Lambda should run a trained .h5 model) the following files:

```
- Dockerfile - app.py - requirements.txt
```

I'm building the Image on a Windows 11 laptop.

**Dockerfile.**

```
# Pull the base image with python 3.8 as a runtime for your Lambda
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variable to disable oneDNN
ENV TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0

# Copy the earlier created requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

# Install the python requirements from requirements.txt
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install TensorFlow and Keras
RUN python3.8 -m pip install tensorflow

RUN python3.8 -m pip install opencv-python

RUN python3.8 -m pip install pillow

RUN python3.8 -m pip install numpy

RUN python3.8 -m pip install boto3


# Copy the earlier created app.py file to the container
COPY app.py ./

# Asigno el CMD para la función Lambda
CMD [ "python3.8", "app.py" ]
```

---

**requirements.txt**

```
# List all python libraries for the lambda
tensorflow==2.13.0
pillow
opencv-python
numpy
boto3
```

---

**app.py**

```
import os
import json
import boto3

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import base64



########################################################################################################

def obtenerModeloS3():
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucketName = 'deteccionRoedores/' # Nombre del bucket
    rutah5 = 'modeloEntrenado/modeloCNN.h5' # Nombre del archivo
    rutaJSON = 'modeloEntrenado/modeloCNN.json' # Nombre del archivo
    
    
    try:
        
        # Nombre del archivo en S3 y el nombre que tendrá en tu función Lambda
        nombre_archivo_local_JSON = '/tmp/modeloCNN.json'
        nombre_archivo_local_H5 = '/tmp/modeloCNN.h5'  # Directorio temporal en Lambda

        # Descarga el archivo .h5 desde S3
        s3.download_file(bucketName, rutah5, nombre_archivo_local_H5)
        #os.rename(nombre_archivo_local_H5, '/var/task/' + rutah5)  # Muevo el archivo .h5 al directorio de trabajo actual 
        
        
        # Hago el mismo proceso con el archivo JSON
        s3.download_file(bucketName, rutaJSON, nombre_archivo_local_JSON)
        #os.rename(nombre_archivo_local_JSON, '/var/task/' + rutaJSON)
        
        print("Archivos descargados correctamente.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
        

########################################################################################################

def decodificarImagen(event):
    
    # Obtén la imagen en base64 del evento
    image_base64 = event['body']

    # Decodifica la imagen en binario
    try:
        image_binary = base64.b64decode(image_base64)
        
        image_path = '/tmp/imagenInput.png'
        
        # Guardo la imagen en el directorio temporal de la Lambda
        with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
            image_file.write(image_binary)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ha ocurrido un error al procesar la imagen recibida ==> " + str(e))

    
    return image_path




########################################################################################################

def cargarModelo():
    
    """Función sin parámetros que trata de acceder a los archivos almacenados con la configuración del modelo
       para cargarlo en memoria y devolverlo para hacer predicciones.
    """
    
    
    
    try:
    
        # cargar json y crear el modelo
        json_file = open('/tmp/modeloCNN.json', 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        loaded_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        
        # cargar pesos al nuevo modelo
        loaded_model.load_weights("/tmp/modeloCNN.h5")
        
        print("Cargado modelo desde disco.")
        
        
        
        # Compilar modelo cargado y listo para usar.
        loaded_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
        
        return loaded_model
    
    except Exception as e:
        print("Ha ocurrido un error al cargar el modelo ==> " + str(e))

########################################################################################################

def deteccionModelo(modeloEntrenado, rutaImagen):
    
    imagenesPrueba = []


    for imagen_nombre in os.listdir(rutaImagen):
        # Construir la ruta completa de la imagen
        imagen_ruta = os.path.join(rutaImagen, imagen_nombre)

        # Cargar la imagen
        img = cv2.imread(imagen_ruta)

        # Verificar si la imagen se cargó correctamente
        if img is not None:
            # Convertir la imagen a escala de grises
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Redimensionar la imagen a un tamaño específico (debes definir 'img_size')
            img = cv2.resize(img, (150, 150))

            # Expandir las dimensiones de la imagen para que coincidan con las expectativas del modelo
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)  # Ahora la forma será (None, 150, 150, 1)
            img = img / 255

            imagenesPrueba.append(img)
            
            break
        
        else:
            print(f"No se pudo cargar la imagen: {imagen_ruta}")
            
            break
            

    imagenesPrueba = np.array(imagenesPrueba)



    # Realizar predicciones y mostrar los resultados
    for imagen in imagenesPrueba:

        if imagen.shape[-1] == 3:  # Si tiene 3 canales, conviértelo a escala de grises
            imagen = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            imagen = np.expand_dims(imagen, axis=-1)  # Ahora la forma será (150, 150, 1)

        # Se lanzan las imágenes contra el modelo para obtener las detecciones.
        predictions = modeloEntrenado.predict(np.expand_dims(imagen, axis=0))
        porcentaje_confianza = predictions[0][0] * 100

            
        #confianza = predictions[0][0] 
        print(f"Confianza de ser un roedor: {porcentaje_confianza}")

        #clase_predicha = class_names[int(round(prediction[0]))]
        #print(f"Roedor: {clase_predicha}")
        
            
            
    return predictions, porcentaje_confianza


########################################################################################################

def generarJSONsalida(porcentaje_confianza, nombre_imagen, resolucion_imagen):
    
    """Función parametrizada que se encarga de generar el JSON de salida con la información
        del análisis del modelo entrenado.
        Parámetros:
            - porcentaje_confianza: Porcentaje de confianza del modelo. Contiene un valor real comprendido entre 0 y 1.
                                    Un valor más alto indica una mayor posibilidad de ser un roedor.
            - nombre_imagen: Nombre de la imagen que se analizó.
            - resolucion_imagen: Resolución de la imagen que se analizó.
    """
    
    
        
    if porcentaje_confianza >= 0.5:
        entidad = "ROEDOR"
    elif porcentaje_confianza < 0.5:
        entidad = "NO ROEDOR"
        
    estructura_json = {
        "resultado": entidad,
        "confianza": porcentaje_confianza,
        "imagen": nombre_imagen,
        "resolucionImagen": resolucion_imagen
    }
    
    json_output = json.dumps(estructura_json)
    
    return json_output


########################################################################################################


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    
    # Si no se encuentra ningún archivo en el directorio de la Lambda, se obtendrán los archivos del modelo de S3
    #if os.listdir('/tmp/') == []:
    #    obtenerModeloS3()
    
    print("Iniciando análisis del modelo..."    )
    
    
    obtenerModeloS3()
    # Antes de ejecutar el modelo, debo procesar la imagen y guardarla como archivo temporal.
    rutaImagen = decodificarImagen(event)
    print("La imagen ha sido procesada y almacenada en ==> " + rutaImagen)
    
    loaded_model = cargarModelo()
    
    resultados, porcentaje_confianza = deteccionModelo(loaded_model, rutaImagen)

    nombres_imagenes = os.listdir(rutaImagen)
    nombre_imagen = nombres_imagenes[0]  # 'nombres_imagenes' solo contiene un elemento.
    
    imagen = Image.open(rutaImagen)
    resolucion_imagen = imagen.size
    
    print(resultados, porcentaje_confianza)
    
    # Genero el JSON de salida del análisis.
    archivoJSON = generarJSONsalida(porcentaje_confianza, nombre_imagen, resolucion_imagen)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=data.json'  # Nombre del archivo JSON que se descargará
        },
        'body': archivoJSON
    }
```

When I build the image in Docker and try to run it in Docker Desktop, I get the following output:
[Docker Desktop's output after running the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J691.png)

You can see how no print() instruction appears on the screen, **despite showing that it is executed "Exited"**.

Finally, if I upload the Image to an ECR container to create a Lambda, when I run the Lambda I get this log in CloudWatch:

[CloudWatch log after running Lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhu27.png)